# Boostrap grid with rowspan inside an Angular-Kendo TabStrip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am having an issue with creating a Bootstrap grid inside an Angular-Kendo UI TabStrip, which is also wrapped in a Bootstrap-UI modal. I need to, however, have `rowspan` type functionality.

I think my conflicts might be with the Angular-Bootstrap modal.

My requirements are: the left side contains two stacked cells, and the right side contains six stacked cells. I have posted an image below of the UI layout.

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OE0VNbSkBHzmw1O4yLxC?p=preview

---

I have found the following post below which reference the same `rowspan` question when building a Bootstrip grid:

[How to design rowspan using bootstrap div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670964/how-to-design-rowspan-using-bootstrap-div)

which also contains a bootply demo: http://www.bootply.com/XrVcAxlbvl#

---

Here is a sample image showing my page design. Now I need to build the Bootstrap rows and cols :

[image: UI Design]

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140070/bootstrap-3-grid-system-does-not-work-correctly-within-a-3rd-party-styled-div-k

Comment: @ezanker - You need to put that as your answer because that post exactly answers this issue. It's the Kendo CSS setting `box-sizing: content-box`  which needs to be overridden to `border-box` on each page which uses Bootstrip `.rows` or `.col` classes.

Comment: I put it as the answer.

Comment: If I had been more diligent, I would have found those docs on my own - and saved myself a lot of time. :-)